# Index type for nested object based on type of

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There are already some answers on SO about this topic, but they all seem to be outdated. I want to select a component based on the given types. I prefer to use `typeof` to auto generate the types of the object. What is the correct way to declare the types for the `Comp` component?

```
const icons = {
  default: {
    coffee: IconCoffee,
  },
  service: {
    coffee: IconCoffeeService,
  },
} as const;


const Comp = icons[iconSet][iconName];
```

Currently, getting the following error: `type 'string' can't be used to index type`

Comment: The real question is what the [record type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) of `icons` should be, at opposed to the object type that is inferred. Is it correct to say its type is `icons: Record<string, Record<string, React.Component<...>>>`?

Comment: You will have to assert that `iconSet` and `iconName` are constant strings, maybe when you declare them you can write `const iconSet: 'default' | 'service'` or cast it to constant string like `icons[iconSet as 'service'][iconName as 'coffee']`

Comment: @concat, that seems to be the right answers. Since this selector selects an icon based on a given API response this will be the right type for this use case. 

`const icons: Record<string, Record<string, React.MemoExoticComponent<(props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => JSX.Element>>>`

Answer (score 0):

Object literals are typed by default as the exact object types that are encoded, rather than as a dictionary, or [a `Record` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) as TS calls it. To index into an object literal with arbitrary strings, we need to declare its type explicitly as a record, in this case, a nested record:

```js
const icons:
  Record<string, Record<string, React.MemoExoticComponent<(props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => JSX.Element>>>
  = { ... }
declare const iconSet: string;
declare const iconName: string;
const Comp = icons[iconSet][iconName];
```